# force a a radio box to be be checked value in jquery mobile

Tags: checkbox, jquery-mobile

How do a force a a radio box to be be checked value in jquery mobile?
I think it has to do with class=ui-btn-active.

```
<input type='radio' name='myradio' id='radio-choice-1' value='1' /><label for='radio-choice-1'>Station 1</label>
<input type='radio' name='myradio' id='radio-choice-2' checked value='2' /><label for='radio-choice-2'>Station 2</label> 
<input type='radio' name='myradio' id='radio-choice-3' value='3' /><label for='radio-choice-3'>Station 3</label>
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure what you mean by 'force' - are you asking how to programatically change the state of a radio button? With jQuery Mobile, you must refresh the radio button after updating it's attribute in order for it's UI to be updated. [From the docs](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0b2/#/demos/1.0b2/docs/forms/radiobuttons/index.html):

```
$("input[type='radio']").attr("checked",true).checkboxradio("refresh");
```

Also note that with HTML4, [boolean attributes](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/intro/sgmltut.html#h-3.3.4.2) such as `disabled` and `checked` take their names as values when enabled. So simply putting in `checked` is not valid but must be `checked='checked'` instead.